# how to wait wget finished to get more resources

Tags: bash, wget

I am new to bash.

I want to wget some resources in parallel.

What is the problem in the following code:

```
for item in $list
do
  if [ $i -le 10 ];then
    wget -b $item
    let "i++"
  else
    wait
    i=1
  fi
```

When I execute this shell. Error throwed:

```
fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

My question is how to use wget right way.

### Edit:

My problem is there is about four thousands of url to download, if I let all these jobs work in parallel, fork: Resource temporarily unavailable will throw out. I don't know how to control the count in parallel.

Comment: `wget -b $item` launch `wget` in the foreground. Use `wget -b $item &` to launch in the background and allow parallelization. Note that variable `i` looks uninitialized...

Comment: Note that the [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) utility does what you want and much more.

Comment: `wget "$item" &` (instead of `wget -b`) is also fine to run wget in background; that way, `bash` knows it's background and you can use `jobs` to see/control. I personally prefer `curl` or `lftp`; I rarely use `wget`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet after i spent some time on this, i found i just need to change `wget -b $item` to `wget $item &`. yeah, that is what you just said. so what is the difference between `-b` and `&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `jobs|grep` to check background jobs:

```
#!/bin/bash

urls=('www.cnn.com' 'www.wikipedia.org')  ## input data

for ((i=-1;++i<${#urls[@]};)); do
  curl -L -s ${urls[$i]} >file-$i.html &  ## background jobs
done

until [[ -z `jobs|grep -E -v 'Done|Terminated'` ]]; do
  sleep 0.05; echo -n '.'                 ## do something while waiting
done

echo; ls -l file*\.html                   ## list downloaded files
```

Results:

```
............................
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 155421 Jan 20 00:50 file-0.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx  74711 Jan 20 00:50 file-1.html
```

---

Another variance, tasks in simple parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash

urls=('www.yahoo.com' 'www.hotmail.com' 'stackoverflow.com')

_task1(){                                  ## task 1: download files
  for ((i=-1;++i<${#urls[@]};)); do
    curl -L -s ${urls[$i]} >file-$i.html &
  done; wait
}
_task2(){ echo hello; }                    ## task 2: a fake task
_task3(){ echo hi; }                       ## task 3: a fake task

_task1 & _task2 & _task3 &                 ## run them in parallel
wait                                       ## and wait for them

ls -l file*\.html                          ## list results of all tasks
echo done                                  ## and do something
```

Results:

```
hello
hi
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 320013 Jan 20 02:19 file-0.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx   3566 Jan 20 02:19 file-1.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 253348 Jan 20 02:19 file-2.html
done
```

---

Example with limit how many downloads in parallel at a time (max=3):

```
#!/bin/bash

m=3                                            ## max jobs (downloads) at a time
t=4                                            ## retries for each download

_debug(){                                      ## list jobs to see (debug)
  printf ":: jobs running: %s\n" "$(echo `jobs -p`)"
}

## sample input data
## is redirected to filehandle=3
exec 3<<-EOF
www.google.com google.html
www.hotmail.com hotmail.html
www.wikipedia.org wiki.html
www.cisco.com cisco.html
www.cnn.com cnn.html
www.yahoo.com yahoo.html
EOF

## read data from filehandle=3, line by line
while IFS=' ' read -u 3 -r u f || [[ -n "$f" ]]; do
  [[ -z "$f" ]] && continue                  ## ignore empty input line
  while [[ $(jobs -p|wc -l) -ge "$m" ]]; do  ## while $m or more jobs in running
    _debug                                   ## then list jobs to see (debug)
    wait -n                                  ## and wait for some job(s) to finish
  done
  curl --retry $t -Ls "$u" >"$f" &           ## download in background
  printf "job %d: %s => %s\n" $! "$u" "$f"   ## print job info to see (debug)
done

_debug; wait; ls -l *\.html                  ## see final results
```

Outputs:

```
job 22992: www.google.com => google.html
job 22996: www.hotmail.com => hotmail.html
job 23000: www.wikipedia.org => wiki.html
:: jobs running: 22992 22996 23000
job 23022: www.cisco.com => cisco.html
:: jobs running: 22996 23000 23022
job 23034: www.cnn.com => cnn.html
:: jobs running: 23000 23022 23034
job 23052: www.yahoo.com => yahoo.html
:: jobs running: 23000 23034 23052
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx  61473 Jan 21 01:15 cisco.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 155055 Jan 21 01:15 cnn.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx  12514 Jan 21 01:15 google.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx   3566 Jan 21 01:15 hotmail.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx  74711 Jan 21 01:15 wiki.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 319967 Jan 21 01:15 yahoo.html
```

---

After reading your updated question, I think it is much easier to use [lftp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lftp), which can **log and download** (automatically follow-link + retry-download + continue-download); you'll never need to worry about job/fork resources because you run only a few lftp commands. Just plit your download list into some smaller lists, and `lftp` will download for you:

```
$ cat downthemall.sh 
#!/bin/bash

## run: lftp -c 'help get'
## to know how to use lftp to download files
## with automatically retry+continue

p=()                                     ## pid list

for l in *\.lst; do
  lftp -f "$l" >/dev/null &              ## run proccesses in parallel
  p+=("--pid=$!")                        ## record pid
done

until [[ -f d.log ]]; do sleep 0.5; done ## wait for the log file
tail -f d.log ${p[@]}                    ## print results when downloading
```

Outputs:

```
$ cat 1.lst 
set xfer:log true
set xfer:log-file d.log
get -c http://www.microsoft.com -o micro.html
get -c http://www.cisco.com     -o cisco.html
get -c http://www.wikipedia.org -o wiki.html

$ cat 2.lst 
set xfer:log true
set xfer:log-file d.log
get -c http://www.google.com    -o google.html
get -c http://www.cnn.com       -o cnn.html
get -c http://www.yahoo.com     -o yahoo.html

$ cat 3.lst 
set xfer:log true
set xfer:log-file d.log
get -c http://www.hp.com        -o hp.html
get -c http://www.ibm.com       -o ibm.html
get -c http://stackoverflow.com -o stack.html

$  rm *log *html;./downthemall.sh
2018-01-22 02:10:13 http://www.google.com.vn/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=leVkWqiOKfLs8AeBvqBA -> /tmp/1/google.html 0-12538 103.1 KiB/s
2018-01-22 02:10:13 http://edition.cnn.com/ -> /tmp/1/cnn.html 0-153601 362.6 KiB/s
2018-01-22 02:10:13 https://www.microsoft.com/vi-vn/ -> /tmp/1/micro.html 0-129791 204.0 KiB/s
2018-01-22 02:10:14 https://www.cisco.com/ -> /tmp/1/cisco.html 0-61473 328.0 KiB/s
2018-01-22 02:10:14 http://www8.hp.com/vn/en/home.html -> /tmp/1/hp.html 0-73136 92.2 KiB/s
2018-01-22 02:10:14 https://www.ibm.com/us-en/ -> /tmp/1/ibm.html 0-32700 131.4 KiB/s
2018-01-22 02:10:15 https://vn.yahoo.com/?p=us -> /tmp/1/yahoo.html 0-318657 208.4 KiB/s
2018-01-22 02:10:15 https://www.wikipedia.org/ -> /tmp/1/wiki.html 0-74711 60.7 KiB/s
2018-01-22 02:10:16 https://stackoverflow.com/ -> /tmp/1/stack.html 0-253033 180.8
```

Comment: It's better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131484/wait-for-bash-background-jobs-in-script-to-be-finished

Comment: thanks for your answer, my problem is there is about four thousands of url to download, if I let all these jobs work in parallel, `fork: Resource temporarily unavailable` will throw out. I don't know how to control the count in parallel.

Comment: if you want 10 downloads in parallel, then run 10 tasks in parallel, each task download a list of file sequentially; however, i recommend to use a full function downloader, not a bash script, if you really to download that many files

Comment: how can I achieve this, sorry, I am really new to shell scripting.

Comment: I've add another example, where max=3 files is downloaded concurrently.

Comment: Good description and variants.

Answer (score 2):

With updated question, here is an updated answer.

Following script launches 10 (can be changed to any number) `wget` processes in the background and monitors them. Once one of the process finishes, it gets the next one in the list and tries to keep the same `$maxn`(10) process running in the background, until  it runs out of the urls from the list(`$urlfile`). There are inline comments to help understand.

```
$ cat wget.sh
#!/bin/bash

wget_bg()
{
    > ./wget.pids # Start with empty pidfile
    urlfile="$1"
    maxn=$2
    cnt=0;
    while read -r url
    do
        if [ $cnt -lt $maxn ] && [ ! -z "$url" ]; then # Only maxn processes will run in the background
            echo -n "wget $url ..."
            wget "$url" &>/dev/null &
            pidwget=$! # This gets the backgrounded pid
            echo "$pidwget" >> ./wget.pids # fill pidfile
            echo "pid[$pidwget]"
            ((cnt++));
        fi
        while [ $cnt -eq $maxn ] # Start monitoring as soon the maxn process hits
        do
            while read -r pids
            do
                if ps -p $pids > /dev/null; then # Check pid running
                  :
                else
                  sed -i "/$pids/d" wget.pids # If not remove it from pidfile
                  ((cnt--)); # decrement counter
                fi
            done < wget.pids
        done
    done < "$urlfile"
}    
# This runs 10 wget processes at a time in the bg. Modify for more or less.
wget_bg ./test.txt 10
```

To run:

```
$ chmod u+x ./wget.sh 
$ ./wget.sh
wget blah.com ...pid[13012]
wget whatever.com ...pid[13013]
wget thing.com ...pid[13014]
wget foo.com ...pid[13015]
wget bar.com ...pid[13016]
wget baz.com ...pid[13017]
wget steve.com ...pid[13018]
wget kendal.com ...pid[13019]
```

Comment: I think OP wants to do download things in parallel.

Comment: Not sure why you have to wait if you want all the processes to run in parallel for different urls.

Comment: I think OP wants to do something while waiting for all files to be downloaded, not waiting and do nothing; then he/she would handle the files after all of them are downloaded. Downloading in parallel will be faster, especially when downloading from different sources.

Comment: Ideally, files should be checked if they are downloaded successfully; but, it is another thing, not parallelism technique. I think this question is about parallelism, so, downloading files one by one  sequentially is not really the answer.

Comment: I believe OP's question and example needs a little more clarity than it is now.

Comment: @iamauser sorry for the ambiguity. I have updated my question.

Comment: @jasonxia23 see my updated answer, hope it works for you.

Answer (score -2):

Add this in your if statement :

```
until wget -b $item do
    printf '.'
    sleep 2
done
```

The loop will wait process finished and print a "." every 2sec

Comment: This would retry `wget` until it succeeds, not print `.`s until a single instance completes.