# Wait until the first .jar file is complete before executing the second .jar file in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the following shell script that executes multiple jar files from a folder. The script is working fine but I want the for loop to WAIT until a .jar file execution is complete before starting the execution of the next .jar file in the loop. Below is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "/abc/pqr/"*
  do
    "$i" &
done
wait
```

Comment: Then why are you using `&`?

Comment: to make it keep executing in the background aswell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for bash background jobs in script to be finished](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1131484/608639), [How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish and return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/356100/608639), [Waiting for background processes to finish before exiting script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14254118/608639), etc.

Comment: This make no sense, why send a process in the background if you have to wait for it anyway?  In your `for` loop, you could add an `if then else fi` with `ps -ef` to check if it is still running, but this is overkill IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `&` from inside this script and then run the parent script in the background instead.

`./myScript.sh &`

your for loop will execute the jars in turn, waiting for each one to complete before moving on. The entire process will run in the background.

Comment: Hi, thank you for ur reply. Is there a way to automate this task? I mean could I achieve the same inside the script instead of using & with it while firing it?